# What is the correct way to navigate across tabs in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

In my project I am using Angular 13 / Ionic 6. My project contains tabs for each of the main sections of the app, and then a few of the tabs have sub sections within that tab.

I'm noticing some odd behavior when trying to navigate to a sub section within one of my tabs from another tab.

For example sake, this is my routes for my app:

```
/app/tabs/home
/app/tabs/section1
/app/tabs/section2
/app/tabs/section2/sub-section
```

Here are my routing modules:

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'consent',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/consent/consent.module').then( m => m.ConsentPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'consent',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children:
        [
            {
                path: 'home',
                loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
            },
            {
                path: 'section1',
                loadChildren: () => import('./section1/section1.module').then( m => m.Section1PageModule)
            },
            {
                path: 'section2',
                loadChildren: () => import('./section2/section2.module').then( m => m.Section2PageModule)
            },
            {
                path: 'section3',
                loadChildren: () => import('./section3/section3.module').then( m => m.Section3PageModule)
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

section2-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Section2Page
  },
  {
    path: 'sub-section',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sub-section/sub-section.module').then( m => m.SubSectionPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'sub-section2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sub-section2/sub-section2.module').then( m => m.SubSection2PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'sub-section3',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sub-section3/sub-section3.module').then( m => m.SubSection3PageModule)
  },
];
```

When I try to use the `routerLink` in my `/app/tabs/home` to link to `/app/tabs/section2/sub-section` it creates an odd behavior. There is no animation or slide transition between sections and the screen goes white for a second and then loads the new view.

I even tried to use the Router service from a click method and had the same experience.

Any thoughts around what may be causing this?

Comment: Also, please let me know if I can provide any additional info as my original question may not have been clear enough.

Comment: The flickering is due to animations, not present in the post, so it's complicated to guess. You might find some sources online to try to resolve

Comment: What is `odd behavior` be?

Comment: How are you navigating to the subsections(using other `ion-tabs` or `ion-menu` or just some regular routing using the angular router)? You want the tabs buttons to be always visible even when you're on a subsection?

Comment: @JosemarSilva - Users can navigate to the subsections by clicking on one of the tabs. They are just links within the tab main view into the subsection. The tabs are always present within the app. However, once clicking on a few of the tabs, those present the users with subsection links within the app.

Comment: I meant the subsections (e.g. `section2/sub-section3`). Maybe you should add a new `ion-router-outlet` on the `section2.page.html` and base the navigation to section2 subsections on this router instead of the main one(`routerLink="section2/sub-section"` instead of `routerLink="/app/tabs/section2/sub-section"`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to point out that your concept itself is not "best practice".

If you really need to devide the tabs into subsections then it's better to not use pages but use actual sections within the same page.
Or use idependent pages if the "sections" are not directly related to their respective tabs.

For the moment try adding [a wild card](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#wild-cards) at the end of the routes array. That and navigate with Router.navigate instead of routerlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Angular Animation.

Import the BrowserAnimationsModule.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
]
```

Wrap the Router Outlet

```
import { slider } from './route-animation.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  animations: [ slider ]
})

prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
  return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
}
```

Create route-animation.ts file

```
export const slider =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%'})
      ]),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '100%'}))
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
        ])
      ]),    
      // Required for child animations on the page
       query(':leave', animateChild()),
       query(':enter', animateChild()),
  ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to the modules being fetched. Try preloading them.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```